# How to Build Incremental data loading?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

I found this blog (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-incremental-copy-overview) and tried it, it was very helpful in moving the data b/w sql server and azure database,but how can I build something like this to copy data over in B/w On Prem SQL Server and Azure Datawarehouse??

Are there any links which I can get started with.

I have found various links but they are not very reasonable when I talk about Delta data loading?

Is there any way I can achive this using ADF V1?? or this is only possible using ADF V2??

Answer (score 2):

The change tracking part of the guidance is still relevant. You need some way to figure out what is the incremental data on the SQL Server on-premises instance that need to be pushed to your Azure SQL DW. What's different is how you can push the incremental data to SQL DW.

If you have something built using SSIS, it will work with SQL DW. Download the Azure pack for SSIS to get the SQL DW optimized workflow. ADF can do the same also if you already use it or are ok with spinning up another service.

In the simplest case you can export the incremental data into csv files, push to blob store using azcopy then insert into your SQL DW via external tables. For small data sets, this works just fine and can be automated with scripts to minimize risk and labor. Large data sets will be trickier as inserts are expensive fully logged operations. Check out [Minimal logging with bulk load](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-develop-best-practices-transactions#minimal-logging-with-bulk-load) for hints on how INSERT.....SELECT can be minimally logged and the conditions for it to occur. While partitioning is a valid strategy, it's not a good idea for most environments for daily incremental loads mostly because there isn't enough data to build high quality row groups with clustered column store tables. That can results in poor query performance until the index is rebuilt. Optimizing for a single load operation daily instead of tens, hundreds or thousands of queries daily is usually not the right tradeoff.

Comment: Can Change Tracking be used to push data into the ADW, with multiple data? I have like 1k+ tables thats needs to be inserted into the ADW, Right Now I am trying to use ADF V1, Slice values for data loading, but I found that, I need to set Script in Copy Preview, for each table A/Q to the Datetime column for each table and its quite tedious when we are talking about 1k+ tables also some of my tables dont contain the datetime column that can be used for loading data on each day. I am really stuck in this part, no documentations on whats so ever that can help me in this.

Comment: Today, SQL Data Warehouse doesn't support CDC from SQL Server to incrementally load data. You can use an SSIS workflow, ADF pipeline, or any of the 3rd party certified partners (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-partner-data-integration) to do CDC.

Comment: while matt is correct you can put CDC or change tracking on the source tables (assuming SQL Server, azure DB supports only CT) and use SSIS to load the resulting data. you can also leverage the azure feature pack to automate the use of polybase to load the resulting change set. you would then need to resolve the deltas within SQL DW  using this pattern: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-develop-ctas#replace-merge-statements